# Maintenance in MYSQL when innodb_file_per_table disabled

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, maintenance

I have read your post and I completely understand OPTIMIZE TABLE to perform in an environment where innodb_file_per_table is disabled, does not shrink the global ibdata1 tablespace.

But what if I need to perform index maintenance on InnoDB tables with ANALYZE command, it will grow the single tablespace also?

What other alternatives are there to increase performance or doing some maintenance in Innodb engine, when using a single tablespace and without grow out of control the single ibdata1.

Regards.
Matthew

Answer (score 1):

[**ANALYZE TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html) will read index pages for a table, compute statistics, and store the results in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS`. No writes to `ibdata1` whatsoever.

Notwithstanding, anything DDL-related such as

```
ALTER TABLE ... ADD INDEX ...
ALTER TABLE ... DROP INDEX ...
ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN ...
OPTIMIZE TABLE ...
```

performed against an InnoDB table or its indexes with [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled will make ibdata1 *mercilessly* grow.

There are two things you could try to minimally control (or at least monitor) ibdata1's growth

## ALTERNATIVE #1 : Place a limit on ibdata1 on creation

Perhaps create a large ibdata1

```
ibdata1:innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:100G
```

or set to large initial size and a larger max filesize

```
ibdata1:innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:50G:autoextend:max:100G
```

## ALTERNATIVE #2 : Use a Large Raw Data Device

According to [MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide, Page 428](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127)

[image: MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide]

> Any raw partitions in the configuration must exist but must have the modifier `newraw` listed after the size of the file specification. `newraw` tells InnoDB to initialize the partition when the server starts up. New partitions are treated as read-only after initialization. After InnoDB initializes the tablespace, stop the server change `newraw` to `raw` in the partition specfication, and restart the server. For example, to use a 10GB Unix partition named /dev/hdc6, begin with a configuration like this:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_data_home_dir=
innodb_data_file_path=/dev/hdc6:10Gnewraw
```

> Start the server and let InnoDB initialize the tablespace. Then stop the server and change the configuration from `newraw` to `raw`:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_data_home_dir=
innodb_data_file_path=/dev/hdc6:10Graw
```

> After changing the configuration, restart the server.

## CAVEAT

With either alternate you stop worrying about growth until there is no more room. Otherwise, you must eventually deal with any imposed limits on ibdata1's size.

- `Apr 15, 2012` : [What happens when InnoDB hits its tablespace autoextend max?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16522/what-happens-when-innodb-hits-its-tablespace-autoextend-max/16530#16530)
- `Apr 11, 2012` : [How do you remove fragmentation from InnoDB tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16341/how-do-you-remove-fragmentation-from-innodb-tables/16353#16353)